# Qt compiler error when trying to use QQmlListProperty

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qlist, qquickitem

I'm trying to use QQmlListProperty to expose a QList from within a QQuickItem - and following the documentation at:

- [Properties with Object-List Types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#properties-with-object-list-types)
- [QQmlListProperty Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html)

A simplified example:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QList>
#include <QQmlListProperty>

class GameEngine : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObject> vurms READ vurms)

public:
    explicit GameEngine(QQuickItem *parent = 0) :
        QQuickItem(parent)
    {
    }

    QQmlListProperty<QObject> vurms() const
    {
        return QQmlListProperty<QObject>(this, &m_vurms);
    }

protected:
    QList<QObject*> m_vurms;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

But I'm getting a compiler error on `return QQmlListProperty<QObject>(this, &m_vurms);`:

```
main.cpp:20: error: C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'QQmlListProperty<QObject>'
```

I've also tried replacing the QList of Vurm with a QList of int - the problem seems to be in whatever Qt is doing in `QQmlListProperty<T>(this, &m_vurms);`

I am writing/compiling using Qt 5.8 and C++11 is set in the .pro file. I'm compiling in Qt Creator 4.2.1 on Windows 10: using MSVC 2015 64-bit for compiling.

Comment: Try removing the `const` qualifier from the function.

Comment: @Mitch - the error remains even when not using the qualifier, and as I read the documentation, the const needs to be there...

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in the docs... it's const in the declaration, but not in the definition. Maybe the issue is with `Vurm` - can you provide the header file?

Comment: @Mitch - yeah, it is nothing in the Vurm class - the error happens even with `QList<int>`

Comment: Then I would suggest that you provide a simplified example that we can test ourselves.

Comment: I'm not sure how much simpler this could be - but I've replaced all the <Vurm> templates with <int> ones instead

Comment: A nice simple example is one where we can run it from one file, ideally (especially when it's only C++). I've edited in an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed this earlier, but you need to pass a reference as the second argument to the constructor, not a pointer:

```
QQmlListProperty<Vurm> GameEngine::vurms()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<Vurm>(this, m_vurms);
}
```

I also had to remove the `const` qualifier to get it to compile, which makes sense, given that the constructor of `QQmlListProperty` expects a non-const pointer. The error probably remained when you tried removing it because you were still passing a pointer.

Comment: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/190372/ for the mismatch in the docs.

Comment: +1 for *I also had to remove the const qualifier to get it to compile*. That was the issue for me. Thanks for the help!